# How to expose filter for entity reference as dropdown in the Search API view?

Tags: 7, views, search

In my Search API view, I'd like an *Exposed filter > Entity reference* to be a select box, not a text field.

#### Details

I have a view which I created like:

- *Views > Add new view > Show: default node index*

So it uses the Search API index as a basis.

In the Search API I have ticked to index `field_entity` which is an `Entity reference > Content_type: entity` (confusing naming, I know).

I want the user to go to the views page & be able to filter the view results by `field_entity` (which is an exposed filter/entity reference).

The issue is the view shows the exposed filter as a text field. I have edited `field_entity` & checked the box `Render Views filters as select list` - this works fine for a normal view but not for a Search API view.

#### Question

Can I somehow convert this text field to a select box?

---

To clarify, I cannot use custom or contributed modules on this project, so it needs to be done without using hooks, or other modules, etc.

[image: Drupal 7, Search API Views]

Comment: I assume Drupal 7? Have you looked at [better exposed filters module](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters)?

Comment: Yes D7, sorry should have also mentioned we can't install contrib modules! Weird project I know, long story. Thanks though, will update original question.

Comment: Oh ok sorry missed that in your OP. Can you use custom logic in Views templates?

Comment: Yes! I think we can, since we can edit the theme layer. We also have access to a few pre-installed contrib modules, such as display suite / DS extras, but we can't install new contrib modules. No better exposed filters unfortunately :(

Comment: sorry for delayed response. you should be able to fix that field with some logic in [views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7.x-3.x) would that work within your parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TYPE => String. This work for me. [image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It would be better, especially for non-sighted users, if your answer could be a bit more descriptive than just including the image. It also helps to save the information if the image were to be come unavailable.